# concatenate firstname and lastname and fill into name field in odoo

Tags: field, odoo, readonly

I have module which has three fields
•name
•first name 
•last name
When a user press save 
The first name and last name will concatenate and displayed in name field.
Name Field must be in read only mode.

```
def onchange_name(self, cr, uid, ids, firstname, lastname, context=None):
        value = {'fullname' : True}
        if firstname and lastname:
            value['fullname'] = firstname + " " +lastname   
        return {'value': value}


<field name="fullname" readonly="True" on_change="onchange_fullname(fullname,context)"/>
<field name="firstname" string="First name" on_change="onchange_name(firstname,lastname,context)"/>                    
 <field name="lastname" string="Last name" on_change="onchange_name(firstname,lastname,context)"/>
```

Comment: which version are you using? v7 or v8 ?

Comment: i m using odoo 8.@AlessandroRuffolo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the model, redefine the *name* field as computed and stored:

```
name = fields.Char(compute='comp_name', store=True)
```

then define the compute method:

```
@api.depends('first_name','last_name')
def comp_name(self):
    self.name = (self.first_name or '')+' '+(self.last_name or '')
```

this way you can remove the *on_change*

Comment: there is little error or else code is running.                                         unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str'

Comment: i updated, of course if fields are empty, they are seen as *False*

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    name = str(vals['first_name'] or '') + ' ' +str(vals['last_name'] or '')
    vals['name'] = name
    return super(sample_model, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```