# Put in _rec_name a combination of two fields in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Hi I have the following model:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from odoo import models, fields, api

class myclass(models.Model):
    _name = 'myproject.myclass'
    _rec_name = 'field1'

     field1= fields.Char('Field1', size=64, required=True)
     field2= fields.Char('Field2', size=64, required=True)
     field3= fields.Char('Field3', size=64, required=True)


def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    res = []
    fields= self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
    for field in fields:
        res.append((field .id, field.field1+ ' ' + field.field2))
    return res
```

The problem is that Odoo only print the field in `_rec_name`, ie, `'field1'`.

I test solutions in:

[concatenate firstname and lastname and fill into name field in odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308194/concatenate-firstname-and-lastname-and-fill-into-name-field-in-odoo)

https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-display-custom-value-in-many2one-field-in-odoo-11-144209

https://gist.github.com/vijoin/b370e68a06d89af5b354

Comment: Is this Odoo 11 if so why are you using old api syntax, and name_get is the one responsible of showing the value of recname, if you check the code of name_get in Model class you will see that it checks if recname field witch is name by default exists in the model if so whow it if not use the special format model.name and the id. So if it still showing recname this means you didn't override name_get properly

Comment: Please check indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick to the new API and also try to stick to some coding guidelines. Two very obvious things are the class name and the variable name `field` which is a business object record and not a field.

```py
class MyClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'myproject.myclass'
    _rec_name = 'field1'

     field1 = fields.Char('Field1', size=64, required=True)
     field2 = fields.Char('Field2', size=64, required=True)
     field3 = fields.Char('Field3', size=64, required=True)

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        res = []
        for record in self:
            res.append((record.id, "%s %s" % (record.field1, record.field2)))
        return res
```

Comment: Hi, thanks u very much, its works!!, but there is a missing parenthesis in res.apend.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it.